# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Spree::Home#index

Tags: spree

I was trying to remove spree fancy. And when i tried to load the site i got this error.

ActionView::MissingTemplate in Spree::Home#index
Showing /var/www/mystore/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

Missing partial spree/home/slider, spree/store/slider, spree/base/slider, application/slider with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :rabl], :versions=>[:v1]}. Searched in:
  * "/var/www/mystore/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-81a0fbb2db15/lib/views/backend"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-81a0fbb2db15/lib/views/frontend"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bundler/gems/spree_gateway-ea9dd0468485/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spree_frontend-2.2.2/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spree_backend-2.2.2/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spree_api-2.2.2/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spree_core-2.2.2/app/views"
  * "/home/spree/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"

```
Extracted source (around line #2):
1 <% content_for :subheader do %>
2 <%= render 'slider' %>
3 <% end %>
```

But localhost:3000/products is working perfectly fine. Only the index page is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spree_fancy overrides the home/index view. Seems you did not replace that one for the default.
Check that https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/master/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb has thn reporting lines

```
<% content_for :subheader do %>
  <%= render 'slider' %>
<% end %>
```

But https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb doesn't